# Flex and Ant: How do I include other folders via ant script?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant

I currently have a Flex project that was done in Eclipse, using the following compiler settings:

Flex Build Path: (Source Path) includes source folders from other areas, i.e common_components, which aren't projects on their own but just folders with various code I need to share. This works fine but I want to migrate to using ant.

I have read in places on how to include libraries, via compiler.include-libraries, but as this isn't a library but rather just bunch of folders with .as and MXML files, how do i accomplish this?

Comment: Please reword this question.  It's overly broad and we have no idea what you're trying to accomplish?  What have you tried?  Where your build script? I will have to vote to close if no other information is given.

Comment: Sorry did not receive response via email so i didn't see your comment. Revising question above right now. hang on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into adding source paths so that the compile can look at more than one place for your classes.  You can do that by adding new [compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html).

The compiler option you're looking for is `source-path path-element [...]`.